# I can't load resource from a multi module maven project

Tags: java, maven

noob here, I have a multi module maven project but I can't load a xml file under resources folder.
structure of the project:

[image]

and the `TestClass` source code is like the following snippet which is I stole from the internet:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        TestClass test = new TestClass();
        InputStream is = test.getFileFromResourceAsStream("general-analyser-job.xml");
    }
    private InputStream getFileFromResourceAsStream(String fileName) {

            ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
            InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);

            if (inputStream == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("file not found! " + fileName);
            } else {
                return inputStream;
            }
        }
    }
```

`inputStream` is alwayse null!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you don't need to add

```
<resources>
  <resource>
      <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
  </resource>
...
```

You can simply remove that part because it's the default (convention over configuration).

Furthermore you should put your test class `TestClass.java` into `src/test/java` plus a package name. You shouldn't put the `TestClass` directory into `src/main/java` which is the default package which shouldn't being used.

To access the resource you could go like this:

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/general...");
```

Based on your post I'm not sure if `TestClass` is really meant as test or as test implementation for production code later on. If so you should move it into a real package and rename it to something more useful.

Answer (score 0):

try to put your `xml` file into `src/test/resources` and then use code like below:

```
InputStream is = TestClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("general-analyser-job.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, it was silly one: in `pom.xml` of the module under `build` tag resources get excluded like:

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
               <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
</build>
```

just comment out `<excludes>` and everything works